# How do I expand the root's volume size?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, lvm, zfs, ubuntu-18.04

I have Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS running off a 16GB SanDisk USB pendrive in my server. From what I can remember, when I installed Ubuntu on there I had enabled LVM support. For some reason, when I `ssh` into my server, it says `/ is using 99.6% of 3.87GB`, but doing `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdm` says:

```
Disk /dev/sdm: 14.6 GiB, 15664676864 bytes, 30595072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 7DF91AEG-9DE1-43B2-A7C7-EB564B51FEB2

Device       Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdm1     2048     4095     2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdm2     4096  2101247  2097152    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdm3  2101248 30593023 28491776 13.6G Linux filesystem
```

And output from `(parted) print` with /dev/sdm selected gives me:

```
Model: SanDisk Cruzer Glide (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdm: 15.7GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  1076MB  1074MB  ext4
 3      1076MB  15.7GB  14.6GB
```

Running `sudo df -h` gives me:

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                12G     0   12G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              2.4G  241M  2.2G  10% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  3.9G  3.9G     0 100% /
tmpfs                               12G     0   12G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                               12G     0   12G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6034
/dev/loop1                          90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6130
/dev/sdm2                          976M  155M  755M  17% /boot
tmpfs                              2.4G     0  2.4G   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop3                          92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/6259
```

I have left out my ZFS volume above, as it's unnecessary to include it.

Running `sudo vgs` gives me:

```
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- 13.58g 9.58g
```

And, lastly, running `sudo lvs` gives me:

```
  LV        VG        Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 4.00g
```

`/dev/sdm` is my root drive by the way. Any insight to this would be helpful. I do have ZFS installed managing other disks, but `/` is ext3 or 4.

One other thing to note is that I have LVM enabled because if my USB drive were to ever go bad I wanted to be able to restore the data to a new drive, whether it is smaller or larger than 16GB, and utilize the whole disk.

Comment: Found out that the journal logs were taking up about ~290MB. purging them using `sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=2d` gave me enough free space to perform the actions Michael suggested.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As you can see, there's about 9.58 GiB free in your volume group, so that's how much space you can add to the logical volume.

First, you can use `lvextend` to extend the size of the logical volume, to fill up the remaining space:

```
sudo lvextend --extents +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

Now, you can resize the filesystem in that logical volume.

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

Finally, you can see the end result:

```
sudo df -h /
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried `sudo lvextend --extents +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` and it says: `/etc/lvm/archive/.lvm_ubuntu-server_21283_417376161: write error failed: No space left on device`

Comment: @leetbacoon Yes, you do need at least a tiny bit of free space available to complete this. You should delete some files you don't need, such as old logs or whatever.